# How to show Flutter Web route name in the URL with onGenerateRoute?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm using onGenerateRoute parameter on MaterialApp for routing.

```
MaterialApp(
  ...
  onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
  ...
)
```

And then use `pushNamed()`.

I want to show my route names in the url but I can't achieve that with onGenerateRoute.

If I use `routes:` in MaterialApp,

like this:

```
  MaterialApp(
    ...
    routes: {sliverScreen: (context) => SliverScreen()},
    ...
  )
```

It  works. But I think it's redundant if I have provided onGenerateRoute on MaterialApp.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add `name` to generated route, and it will appear in the URL:

```dart
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: ... ,
    settings: RouteSettings(name: 'SOMENAME'))
```

Comment: When I use the web builder (`flutter run -d chrome` or `flutter build web`), I think it's better to put a slash in front of 'SOMENAME'. That is: `settings: RouteSettings(name: '/SOMENAME'))` makes the url http://localhost:55525/#/SOMENAME

I don't know what the # is there for in the web building, but I'm not questioning it.

Comment: @chongman There are two client-side routing mode: `hash` based and `history api` based. The first one is more robust (but less beauty). I believe, that in stable `flutter for web` release we'll be able to choose one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use this on `onGenerateRoute`:

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) => RouteGenerator.generateRoute(settings),
```

And while returning `MaterialPageRoute` from the route file just add settings:

```
return MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: settings,
    builder:(_) => HomeWeb()
);
```